# An equation about divisor function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisor-sum

We define the 2th divisor function as follows: $\sigma_2(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}d^2$?

> Is there infinite positive integer $n$ such that  $\sigma_2(n)=(n+3)^2$? If there is, how can we find the least $n$?

Comment: Please edit to include your efforts.  A simple search would appear to be the obvious place to start.

Comment: @lulu I'm sorry,I let $n=\prod p_k^{a_k}$ and we sufficient to solve the equation $\prod\left(\sum_{i=0}^{a_i}p_k^{2i}\right)=\left(\prod p_k^{a_k}+3\right)^2$,but I don't think it is a feadible method,and I have no others idea.

Comment: Obvious ideas: A.  do a search!  Took me less than 10 seconds to find an example (with a computer of course.  There is an example $<500$).  B.  Show that $n$ can not be prime.  C.  Consider the case of a semiprime.  The least solution is a semiprime.  The second one I have found is a semiprime but I don't know if it is actually the second smallest or not.

Comment: Should say:  I doubt it will be possible to settle the infinitude question, though who knows?

Comment: I found only $2$ solutions so far , $287=7\cdot 41$ and $9799=41\cdot 239$

Comment: @Peter  Those are the only ones I found as well.   Sticking to semiprimes, I looked at solutions to the associate Pell like equation but didn't find any other prime pairs. Maybe one can prove that the only examples would be semiprimes, I didn't try.

Comment: @lulu I had this idea as well and in fact, further semiprime solutions are very , very unlikely. Next step is to rule out more than $2$ prime factors.

Comment: @ReinhardtΩ a better thing to do would be to note the properties of the function before trying to answer the question. That would help in deciding where the passage to the solution lies.

Comment: For example, if $p$ is prime, $\sigma_2(p) = p^2 + 1 \implies p \mid \sigma_2(p)-1$

Comment: Also, for $p^k$ (where $p$ is prime), $\sigma_2(p^k) = 1 + p^2 + p^4 + \dots = \frac{p^{2(k+1)} -1}{p-1}$

Comment: Finding such properties (if any) will be helpful. Euler's totient function has the property $\varphi(m)\varphi(n) = \varphi(mn)$ when $(m,n) = 1$, and this helps in many problems. Such an analysis will help you get the fitting method to address the question.

Comment: @Spectre This only gives a few partial results , but to find out whether there are more solutions will require more advanced approaches.

Comment: @Peter True; I was just giving the OP a starting point though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Sketch**we list the divisors of $n$:$$1=d_1<d_2<\dots<d_k=n$$
then
\begin{aligned}
&1+d_2^w+\cdots+d_{k-1}^2+n^2=(n+3)^2\\
&\iff d_1^2+\cdots+d_{k-1}^2=6n+8
\end{aligned}
now we should estimate the range of$k$.

1. If $k\ge8$,
   \begin{aligned}
   &\quad d_1^2+\cdots+d_{k-1}^2\\&\ge (d_2-d_{k-1})^2+2d_2d_{k-1}+(d_3-d_{k-2})^2+2d_3d_{k-2}+(d_4-d_{k-3})^2+2d_4d_{k-3}\\&\ge 6n+8
   \end{aligned}
   A contradiction!
2. If $3\le k\le 7$,a little difficult
3. $k=2$,let $n=pq$($p,q$ are different prime),then
   $$p^2+q^2=6pq+8$$
   $$\iff (p-3q)^2=8q^2+8$$
   $$\iff q^2-2\left(\frac{p-3q}{4}\right)^2=-1$$
   it is similar to Pell equation!
   $$x^2+2y^2=-1$$
   let
   $$x_n-\sqrt2 y_n=(1+\sqrt2)^{2n-1}$$
   luckily,$$x_2=5,y_2=7\implies p=41,q=7\implies n=287$$
   $$x_3=41,y_3=29\implies p=239,q=41\implies n=9799$$

Comment: It's easy to get this inequality $n\sum{1/p_i^2}\le 6+9/n$
. If the number of primes $\ge 3$ you get at least 3 terms (in the sum) adding to at least $\sum_{\text{cyclic}}{pq/r}$, which is $>3\sqrt[3]{pqr}>9$ (AM-GM), making the first inequality impossible.